# Implementing "$or" with C# driver (Samus) for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

Please, give me some samples of queries in C#
with "$or" logic.
I am using C# driver,
written by Samus (https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp)...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a typed collection (the Person type in this example) you can do an OR using Linq:

```
var mongo = new Mongo("Server=localhost:27017");
mongo.Connect();

List<Person> people = mongo["dbName"].GetCollection<Person>("people").Linq().Where(x => x.Age == 21 || x.Age == 35).ToList();

mongo.Disconnect();
```

At the moment that won't use the "$or" operator (it will use JavaScript for the `||`, see JavaScript Mode [in this wiki page](https://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/wiki/Linq)).

If you really want to use the "$or" operator you could build up a query document and pass an array of conditions to the "$or" operator:

```
var mongo = new Mongo("Server=localhost:27017");
mongo.Connect();

var query = new Document
{
    {"$or", new Document[] { new Document("Age", 21), new Document("Age", 35) } }
};
Document people = mongo["dbName"].GetCollection("people").Find(query);

mongo.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi Can you please show how to do this today using the official C# Drive? (not using Linq)